# I am making a Skydome with light emanating from the bottom, I am trying to get it to have 1 color on one side and another on the other side

Tags: texturing, node-editor, color

What I am essentially asking is how I would make my skydome have 1 color on each side, with one color in between both. [image: Here is one color being put on it, but how would I put one on the other side and one in the middle using nodes?]

Comment: By 'each side' do you mean the outside and the inside?

Answer (score 1):

If by 'each side' you mean outside and inside the dome having different colors, the trick is to use the *Geometry Node* output for *Backfacing* to drive the color selection.  Here's one easy way, using a mix node:

[image: material using a Geometry mode to give different colors to the front and back]

Comment: Thank you! this actually worked